# Error ListView (Android)

Tags: android, eclipse

i have this string:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                      android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);
```

This is Error:

> The constructor ArrayAdapter(new View.OnClickListener(){},
>   int, int, String[]) is     undefined Line
>   breakpoint:ListViewAndroidExample [line: 63] - onClick(View)

```
final Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.amore);
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View v) {
     Button amore = (Button) findViewById(R.id.amore);
     amore.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
     Button amicizia = (Button) findViewById(R.id.amicizia);
     amicizia.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


     listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
     String[] values = new String[] {
      "Amore",
      "Amore",
      "Simple List View In Android",
      "Create List View Android",
      "Android Example",
      "List View Source Code",
      "List View Array Adapter",
      "Android Example List View"
     };


     // Define a new Adapter
     // First parameter - Context
     // Second parameter - Layout for the row
     // Third parameter - ID of the TextView to which the data is written
     // Forth - the Array of data

     ArrayAdapter < String > adapter = new ArrayAdapter < String > (this,
      android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);


     // Assign adapter to ListView
     listView.setAdapter(adapter);

     listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
```

Comment: pass `YourActivityName.this` as first parameter to ArrayAdapter currently you are passing `onClick` context using `this`

Answer (score 3):

Pass `YourClassName.this` in place of `this` in ArrayAdapter's constructor

Answer (score 2):

The ArrayAdapter constructor is defined like this in API:

```
ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, T[] objects)
```

Your Adapter....

```
ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);
```

...is pointing the OnClickListener. If You set something in OnClickListener which needs for example a reference to the Context, You allways will get an Exception, if You do it Your way. The first parameter "this" is pointing to the OnClickListener, but it needs to point to the Context You use, in Your case the Class Context from Your Activity. The correct way would be:

```
 ArrayAdapter(YourClassName.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);
```

Comment: what You mean? Can´t give You the whole code, because You haven´t posted it.